# python adding into list sorted aphabetically

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list like this

```
entries = [{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Hello', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}, 
           {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'}, 
           {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}]
```

I want another list element to add in this list but at the position sorted by "Last Name"

Comment: Can you elaborate further on the at the position sorted by "Last Name" part?

Comment: so you want to add a new element and sort the list by last name?

Comment: What have you tried? If you keep the list always sorted you could write a binary search to find the position to insert into (which would be a more efficient approach than adding and then sorting the entire list)

Comment: it is what I want to do ,new entries get inserted into the correct position in the list (rather than just added to the end) so the list remains sorted alphabetically by last name

Answer (score 2):

You can append the new `dictionary` to the `list` and `sort` the `list` based on the `Last Name`. Here is how you do it:

```
entries = [{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Hello', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}, {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'}, {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}]

new = {'First Name': 'Dean', 'Last Name': 'Jones', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}
entries.append(new)

entries = sorted(entries, key = lambda i: i['Last Name'])
print(entries)
```

Output:

```
[{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Hello', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}, {'First Name': 'Dean', 'Last Name': 'Jones', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}, {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'}, {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}]
```

But this might be time consuming as @Serial Lazer rightly pointed out in the comments. A better solution would be this:

```
entries = [{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Hello', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}, {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'}, {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}]

new = {'First Name': 'Dean', 'Last Name': 'Jones', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}

for index,dictt in enumerate(entries):
    if dictt['Last Name'] > new['Last Name']:
        entries.insert(index,new)
        break

print(entries)
```

Output:

```
[{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Hello', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}, {'First Name': 'Dean', 'Last Name': 'Jones', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}, {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'}, {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}]
```

If you want to insert a `list` of `dictionaries` into `entries`, then the above solutions are not recommended as they are slower. The most efficient way would be to use the `bisect` module, like this:

```
import bisect

entries = [{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Hello', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}, {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'}, {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}]

new = [{'First Name': 'Dean', 'Last Name': 'Jones', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}]

for dictt in new:
    index = bisect.bisect([dict_['Last Name'] for dict_ in entries], dictt['Last Name'])
    entries.insert(index,dictt)

print(entries)
```

Output:

```
[{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Hello', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}, {'First Name': 'Dean', 'Last Name': 'Jones', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}, {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'}, {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}]
```

Comment: Appending data to the list would be quite inefficient using this way. Something that should take O(logN) would take O(NlogN) for each addition of data-point

Comment: Thats improves the insertion to O(N), but still inefficient because we should practically be able to do this in O(logN)

Comment: Why not implement a bisect algo as well for insertion for a complete solution?

Comment: Ok...Will try to implement it in my solution

Comment: @SerialLazer Have implemented `bisect`. Check out my latest edit

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort every time you add info

you can also modify this to take non int values, but they seemed practical

```
entries = [{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Hello', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}, {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'}, {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}]

def addData(first, last, age: int, phone: int):
    entries.append({'First Name': first, 'Last Name': last, 'Age': age, 'Telephone': phone})
    entries.sort(key = lambda x: x['Last Name'])

addData("iron", "key", 18, 1231231234)

print(entries)
```

```
[{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Hello', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'}, {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'}, {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}, {'First Name': 'iron', 'Last Name': 'key', 'Age': 18, 'Telephone': 1231231234}]
```

Comment: Appending data to the list would be quite inefficient using this way. Something that should take O(logN) would take O(NlogN) for each addition of data-point

Answer (score 0):

```
def myFunc(e):
  return e['Last Name']

entries = [{'First Name': 'Sher', 'Last Name': 'Sello', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '2989484'},
           {'First Name': 'Ali', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '398439'},
           {'First Name': 'Talha', 'Last Name': 'Khan', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'}]
entries.append({'First Name': 'Sam', 'Last Name': 'Singh', 'Age': '22', 'Telephone': '3343434'})
entries.sort(key=myFunc)
print(entries)
```

Comment: Whats the advantage of creating a function when you can achieve that using lambda function?